# Install and use nodemon locally

Tags: node.js, npm

I have install nodemon as dev-dependency.

I made a script `"devserver": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js index.js"`

but when I run `npm run devserver` it is giving error `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command` .

Please help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you want to serve `index.js` with nodemon so use nodemon at the start of command.

You dont have to trace the path of nodemon in node modules, after you install it in the project.

```
"devserver": "nodemon index.js"
```

Answer (score 9):

Add "nodemon index.js" to your "start" script of package.json.
Ex.

> "scripts": {
>       "start": "nodemon index.js"
>     }

And then use "npm start" to start using nodemon

Answer (score 8):

Configure your your devserver script as following,

```
"devserver": "nodemon index.js"
```

Or

```
"devserver": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon server.js"
```

**nodemon** will be recognized in current project, if its installed

Comment: Second one is better if you are not using docker. :)